# Outlook mail template variables

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to create variables or use any basic programming logic in an Outlook mail template? An example scenario would be creating a template for a daily report and having today's date automatically filled in (properly formatted) by a date-time variable. Keep in mind that this example scenario is just that, an example, because the type of programming I wish to do is a lot more involved than simply pulling today's date.

So, does Outlook support any programming languages (VBA?) for building mail templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook does allow VBA macros to be defined and run.

To allow VBA editing and other developer tools, follow [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx) according to your version of Outlook:

> **To show the Developer tab for Outlook 2007**
>
> - Start Outlook.
> - On the menu bar, choose Tools, Options.
> - In the Options dialog box, choose the Other tab, and then choose    Advanced Options.
> - In the Advanced Options dialog box, select the Show Developer tab in    the Ribbon check box, and then choose the OK button.
> - Choose the OK button to close the Options dialog box.
>
> **To show the Developer tab for Word 2010, Excel 2010, Outlook 2010, and PowerPoint 2010**
>
> - Start the Office application (Word 2010, Excel 2010, Outlook 2010, or    PowerPoint 2010).
> - Choose the File tab, and then choose Options.
> - In the categories pane, choose Customize Ribbon.
> - In the list of main tabs, choose Developer.

- Choose the OK button to close the Options dialog box.